# Joining 3 Tables from MySQL, and searching join based on user input

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need to join 3 tables and be able to search that join from user input.
The tables are

```
ufoTable, cryptobiologyTable, and unexplainedTable
```

I need to join those and allow the user to search it based on year, and/or location.

I tried

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ufoTable
LEFT JOIN cryptobiologyTable
ON cryptobiologyTable.firstYear = ufoTable.year
LEFT JOIN unexplainedTable
ON unexplainedTable.year = ufoTable.year";
```

But im not sure if its working or how id search that join with the input

For output I need the page to display results based on the users query of the joined tables

Comment: select * 
from ufoTable a, cryptobiologyTable b, unexplainedTable c
where b.firstYear = a.year and c.year = a.year

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from ufoTable a, cryptobiologyTable b, unexplainedTable c
where b.firstYear = a.year and c.year = a.year
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM ufoTable a
    INNER JOIN cryptobiologyTable b ON a.year = b.firstYear 
    INNER JOIN unexplainedTable c ON a.year = c.year 
ORDER BY  a.year
```

Comment: How could I implement a search of that join based on user input of year? like user inputs year 2000 and it outputs only table entries from the join with the year 2000.